# Create a common delta pack bundle of an RCP application that runs in all the OS?

Tags: linux, windows, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp, rcp

Is it possible to create a common delta pack of an RCP application that runs in all the OS(window, Linux,mac etc)?

Comment: Have you tried what was posted here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13496321/build-eclipse-cross-platform-with-maven-tycho ?

Comment: I'm not clear what you mean by 'a common delta pack'.

Comment: I'm create one eclipse RCP application and create product file, i am create delta pack (application setup file) means create one setup file and run cross platform (window, Linux,mac etc). is it possible or not?